# Let $A$ be a $5\times 5$ matrix all of whose eigenvalues are zero. Is $A$ symmetric, anti-symmetric, or $A=-A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $5\times 5$ matrix all of whose  eigenvalues are zero. Which of the following are always true:

a. $A=-A$

b. $A^t=-A$ (anti-symmetric)

c. $A^t=A$ (symmetric)

d. $A^5=0$

For b: Anti-symmetric implies eigenvalues are $0$ (or imaginary), but is the converse true?

For c: I think c is false, intuitively and a counter-example exists.

For d: The characteristic polynomial is of degree 5 and all eigenvalues are zero, so I think d is true.

I have no idea about a. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: $A=-A \Rightarrow 2A=0 \Rightarrow A=0$. And you are right about d).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a is false. It means $2A=0$, and as I suppose you do not work in a field of characteristic $2$, this means $A=0$. Why should it be true?
Here is a $5\times5$ (Jordan) matrix with $0$ as sole eigenvalue, that satisfies neither a, nor b nor c:
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0 &0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about real or complex matrices.

**Hint:** What is the characteristic polynomial of $A$?  Apply the Cayley Hamilton theorem.

If "eigenvalue" in this context specifically means "real eigenvalue", then I suppose you'll need a counterexample.  Note that the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&4\\-1&0}
$$
is not skew-symmetric, but has purely imaginary eigenvalues.

As the other answer says, choice (a) directly implies that $A = 0$.  Is every matrix with $0$-eigenvalues the $0$-matrix?  Try to think of a counterexample.  Upper-traingular matrices are helpful here.